# More Confusion With OOP in Python

Tags: python, oop

Why do I have to pass lyrics for x to print as 4 but not for the two strings? I finally understand parameters and how to satisfy them, but I can't see why I have to pass lyrics for x to print as something other than a memory address unlike bulls_on_parade and happy_bday.

```
class Song():

    def __init__(self, lyrics, x):
        self.lyrics = lyrics
        #self.x = x

    def sing_me_a_song(self):
        for line in self.lyrics:
            print line

    def print_x(self):
        print x.lyrics

happy_bday = Song(["Happy birthday to you,",
               "I don't want to get sued",
               "So I'll stop right there"], 'x-value')

bulls_on_parade = Song(["They'll rally around the family",
                    "With pockets full of shells"], 'x-value')

happy_bday.sing_me_a_song()

bulls_on_parade.sing_me_a_song()

def lyrics(args):
    pass

x = Song(lyrics= 4, x = lyrics)

x.print_x()
```

Comment: You are referring to a global variable "x" in "print_x". That's probably not what you want. But beyond that, I have no idea *what* you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this snippet of code you define the global name `lyrics` to be a function.
Passing `lyrics` as `x = lyrics` to the object constructor for `x` will pass it the function's address (this is not entirely true but for now it will do) as the value for the `x` parameter.

The `lyrics = 4` is different because Python differentiates between function call argument names and variable names.

```
def lyrics(args):
    pass

x = Song(lyrics= 4, x = lyrics)
```

In fact, if, in your code you do this:

```
x = Song(lyrics=lyrics)
print x.lyrics
```

You'll see something like this:

```
<function lyrics at 0x107b9d1b8>
```